# How to end the execution of a function in switch case at default? (or any alternative solutions)

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have this switch case (I post it with the context in case that is important. please tell me if that's annoying.)

```
void getraenk()
{
    //possibilities to choose
    printf("Drinks\n    cola = 1\n    fanta = 2\n    s = 3\n");
    //choose
    int choose;
    float pay;
    scanf("%d", &choose);
    switch (choose) {
        case 1: pay = 1; break;
        case 2: pay = 2; break;
        case 3: pay = 2; break;
        **default: printf("wrong choose"); //<= here is where I want to exit the code**
            break;
    }
    printf("pay %.2f", pay);
   //paying
    float paid;
    scanf("%f", &paid);
    do
    {
        if (paid == pay) {
            printf("here is your ..");
            return;
        }
        else if (paid >= pay)
        {
            printf("change %.2f", paid - pay);
            printf("here is your ..\n");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("please pay %.2f\n", pay - paid);
            float rest;
            scanf("%f", &rest);
            paid = rest + paid;
        }
    }
    while (paid <= pay);
 }
```

I tried to solve this using return after printf("wrong choose")

```
default: printf("wrong choose"), return; break;
```

and return 0

```
default: printf("wrong choose"), return 0; break;
```

but I get both times the error expected expression. Now I tried googling it but there seem to be many cases for that error (which solutions I don't understand as I am a beginner) so I'd be happy if someone could explain me how to interrupt the switch case.

Comment: put a semicolon `;` at the end of your `printf` instead of a comma `,` --> `default: printf("wrong choose"); return; break;`

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error?

Comment: i tried that too then the error drinks function should not return a value

Comment: OHHHH NOW IT WORKS THX SO MUCH @yano

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a break statement after default. I have two suggestions:

1. Remove break and just keep return.
2. Remove both break and return and add exit(0).

Comment: Thank you i didnt know that possibility yet. Going to try it out.

Comment: The leading statement is a bit misleading. `Break` might be needed after a `default`-labeled statement, but it's not needed at the end of the switch body or if you jump elsewhere (like with `return`) before you reach the `break`.

Comment: ok it just appeared when typing the switch so i left it there

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm dumb. I added the semicolon after return 0 and afterwards changed

```
void drinks()//my function
```

to

```
int drinks()
```

and returned 0 as a value after while.
Now it works.